# How can I build Ionic3 angular4 hybrid application as ios .ipa file?

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, macos-sierra, ionic3

I am using a windows machine. So I have installed MAC OS sierra using VMWare in the same machine.

I have developed a Ionic3 Angular4 application with Cordova. 
I have successfully created the .apk file using the command "**`ionic cordova build/run android`**" in my Windows.

So now I want to generate .ipa file. So I just moved the entire project to my MAC OS box. Then installed cordova & Ionic.

Now I am trying to build using command "**`ionic cordova build/run ios`**"

But getting the below error

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer 
directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

So executed `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

But got error `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer” does not exist`

How can overcome these errors and build my ios .ipa file?

Note: **Xcode not installed manually. But installed the Xcode via Terminal (a popup opened and asked to install xcode. So clicked install button. Finally It showed Xcode installed successfully)**

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install xcode. See the cordova [platform guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/) for iOS. And you will also need the xcode commandline-tools (which you already installed). If you want to run you application in a simulator you will also have to install [ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim) (`sudo npm install -g ios-sim@latest`). And for deploying your application to a real device [ios-deploy](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy) (sudo npm install -g ios-deploy@latest)